# SSIS Error "To run a SSIS Package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher"

Tags: ssis

I am trying to run my SSIS Package through a third party tool call Autosys. While running the job I am getting the error "To run a SSIS Package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher".

The job is working perfect in the UAT with the same configuration as Prod with Sql Servies Integration Services 13.0 installed both on them.

I am using SSDT 2015 on both the servers.

Could anyone please help to get this issue resolved.

Please let me know if you need any other information or if I have missed something to mention.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my assumption that Autosys is installed on different system:
1. You need integration service installed on system where you are executing ssis from,no matter what tool you use
2. Check if Autosys and Integration services are installed in same system or install Autosys tool on server where job is working without failure.
Install said service : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/install-integration-services?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thank your for your answer brother. I have tried to create a batch file on the same server SSDT is installed and I am still getting the same error. The package is running fine in SSDT.